# How to add a Texture to a Material using Python?

Tags: python, materials

It looks like it would be easy to add a texture to a material using Python, but no matter what i do i cant figure it out!

I can create a texture using:

```
bpy.data.textures.new("NewTexture", type='IMAGE')
```

and I can create a new material texture slot:

```
bpy.context.object.active_material.texture_slots.add()
```

However i can't link the texture to the Material Slot Texture. I have tried looking through the python API but nothing is working. I would be eternal grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What render engine are you using? Internal?

Comment: I was using the blender internal to automatically find the basecolor, roughness,  and normal channels to quickly create a game ready material so i could see how the models look before i bring them into the game engine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similar to `material_slot.material`, there is a `texture_slot.texture`

(I'm assuming Blender internal from the `texture_slots.add` in q)

```
mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
tex = bpy.data.textures.new("SomeName", 'IMAGE')
slot = mat.texture_slots.add()
slot.texture = tex
```

A simple example using Cycles can be found here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14115/15543

Comment: You are awesome! That was exactly what i was looking for and it worked. Thanks for the link to the Cycles as well

Comment: That doesn't work in 2.8. There is not `material.texture_slots` anymore. There is now both `material.texture_paint_images` and `material.texture_paint_slots`, but both don't have an `add()` method. No idea so far how the 2.8 equivalent should look like.

Comment: I have found [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/118646/82124) which covers that.

Comment: @bluenote10 Thank you so much! I was stuck here. PS THE ABOVE ANSWER IS WRONG FOR BLENDER 2.8.

Comment: ... surprising that an answer from 2016 aimed at blender internal render engine doesn't work in 2.8.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for Blender 3.0

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

mat = bpy.context.active_object.material_slots[0].material

imgpath = '/image path'
img = bpy.data.images.load(imgpath)


mat.use_nodes=True 

#setup the node_tree and links as you would manually on shader Editor
#to define an image texture for a material

material_output = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Material Output')
principled_BSDF = mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')

tex_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
tex_node.image = img

mat.node_tree.links.new(tex_node.outputs[0], principled_BSDF.inputs[0])

#grab mesh data for the active mesh.
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
bpy.ops.uv.unwrap()
uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.active


#assign the uv values for the vertices of each face. This example
#assumes the default cube
for i in range(6):

    loop_data = bm.faces[i].loops
    uv_data = loop_data[0][uv_layer].uv
    uv_data.x = 1.0
    uv_data.y = 0.0

    uv_data = loop_data[1][uv_layer].uv
    uv_data.x = 1.0
    uv_data.y = 1.0

    uv_data = loop_data[2][uv_layer].uv
    uv_data.x = 0.0
    uv_data.y = 1.0

    uv_data = loop_data[3][uv_layer].uv
    uv_data.x = 0.0
    uv_data.y = 0.0

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
```