# Creating a new particle texture using python scripting

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, particles

How would I create a new texture for a particle system? I tried **bpy.ops.texture.new()** but that wouldn't create any type of texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after run:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.texture.new()
```

you can see the "new" texture from:

[image]

/// update

*///////////////**

you can change the current texture to the "new one" with a simple code.. in this case my material name is 'Material', and after that you can change anything, for example I apply the new texture and change the type from CLOUDS :

```
import bpy

D = bpy.data
ob = bpy.context.active_object

bpy.ops.texture.new()
text =bpy.data.textures[len(bpy.data.textures)-1]
mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
slots = mat.texture_slots
for slot in slots:
    try:
        slot.texture = text
        bpy.data.textures[text.name].type = 'CLOUDS'
    except:
        print("empty slot")
```

ACTUALLY , you have some better options to add textures, as [texture slot add](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48584/how-to-add-a-texture-to-a-material-using-python):

```
mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
tex = bpy.data.textures.new("SomeName", 'IMAGE')
slot = mat.texture_slots.add()
slot.texture = tex
```

Comment: Sorry but I have a few mores questions. How would I use this texture in a script and how would I specify which type of texture it is?

Comment: @bunnybot5555, I update the answere, I hope this help you

Comment: When I do the operation tex = bpy.data.textures.new("SomeName", 'IMAGE') What I get is > TypeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.texture.new" error, expected a
> string enum in ('INVOKE_DEFAULT', 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN',
> 'INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS', 'INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW', 'INVOKE_AREA',
> 'INVOKE_SCREEN', 'EXEC_DEFAULT', 'EXEC_REGION_WIN',
> 'EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS', 'EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW', 'EXEC_AREA',
> 'EXEC_SCREEN') Can you help in this? Thanks.

Comment: @ShuangjunLiu There is a difference between `bpy.ops.textures.new()` operator (the call to create the error message above) and `bpy.data.textures.new(...)` your stated script.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/56714)