# bpy.data.textures.new(...) error to create new textures

Tags: texturing, scripting

In one discussion, they provide a way to creat textures in blender
[Creating a new particle texture using python scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70946/creating-a-new-particle-texture-using-python-scripting/108539?noredirect=1#comment191605_108539)

I listed the key part here

```
mat = bpy.data.materials['Material']
tex = bpy.data.textures.new("SomeName", 'IMAGE')
slot = mat.texture_slots.add()
slot.texture = tex
```

However, when I ran the command

```
 tex = bpy.data.textures.new("SomeName", 'IMAGE')
```

What I get is error

> TypeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.texture.new" error, expected a
>   string enum in ('INVOKE_DEFAULT', 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN',
>   'INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS', 'INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW', 'INVOKE_AREA',
>   'INVOKE_SCREEN', 'EXEC_DEFAULT', 'EXEC_REGION_WIN',
>   'EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS', 'EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW', 'EXEC_AREA',
>   'EXEC_SCREEN')

It seems that there are multiple overloaded versions of function 
 bpy.data.textures.new() and bpy.data.textures.new(...)

How can we use them correctly?

Comment: The error message is from incorrectly calling the operator `bpy.ops.texture.new()`  not the API method `bpy.data.textures.new()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select manually or by script object on which this texture will be applied. If the model is selected it should be highlighted or press 'R' the model should be able to rotate.