# Change material texture by loading an external .png file with Python

Tags: python, texturing

I'm trying to change the texture of an object by changing the .png texture image I'm loading from an external folder.

When using the Blender interface, all I need to do is going to the image tab in texture and open the file I want:

[image]

then

[image]

The changes are then operated automatically.

How would I go about to do the same in Python?

I have read other stackexchange answers to [similar questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48584/how-to-add-a-texture-to-a-material-using-python) but I'm not sure to what extent they apply to my situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say I have a plane with an image texture called leaf1.png and I want to change the texture to leaf2.png.

If I hover my mouse over the source area, I can see some text at the bottom of the tooltip that says how to access that data with python. Like this:

[image]

From this, I know that I can access this with python using `bpy.data.images['leaf1.png'].filepath`

So to change the image source with python, I do:

```
import bpy

bpy.data.images['leaf1.png'].filepath = 'path/to/leaf2.png'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer clearly does what I was trying to do, but there is one point that somewhat troubles me, namely that that 
bpy.data.images['leaf1.png'].filepath is now equal to '...leaf2.png'. Is there a way that I could have the command that handles the texture become bpy.data.images['leaf2.png'].filepath ?

Comment: "leaf1.png" is the image name. You can change that too. Just hover your mouse over the leaf1.png and you'll see `bpy.data.images['leaf1.png'].name` is the python. So you could set the name to "leaf2.png", then use that name to change the filepath. But what's in a name?

Comment: You can enable/disable those 'python tooltips' in the preferences

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.1, one can do this:

```
import bpy

# Step 1 - Add Box
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
box_obj      = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
box_obj.name = 'MyBox'

# Step 2 - Material
box_material_obj = bpy.data.materials.new(box_obj.name + '-Material')
box_material_obj.use_nodes = True

bsdf           = box_material_obj.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
texImage       = box_material_obj.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load('myimage.png')
box_material_obj.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], texImage.outputs['Color'])
box_obj.data.materials.append(box_material_obj)
```

Inspired from [this blog by paperspace.com](https://blog.paperspace.com/basics-of-adding-background-images-and-textures-to-your-3-d-models/)