# Rendering with a different texture filename using texture node without manually changing filename each time

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, command-line

Rendering with a different texture filename using the texture node without manually changing the filename each time.

I have several different texture files that i want to render out using the same node group setup and blender file.  is it possible to automate the renders but **use a different texture filename in the texture node group**?  I know about doing a render from the terminal.

Example of rendering from the terminal below:

```
#Render animation in EEVEE from frame 0 to 100 from terminal in Linux
/snap/bin/blender -b /home/jp/Documents/My\ Documents/blender/texture_test.blend -E BLENDER_EEVEE -o /tmp/frame_eevee_##### -s 0 -e 100 -t 1 -a; espeak 'done with eevee render animation'
```

An example of what I'm trying to do is

1. I have a node group in a blender file that has several image files that I want to render using the same node group and blender file.  I have a list of files `p1.png, p2.png, file_texture.png, block_text.png, etc...` and each time it renders **I want it to loop through and replace the texture image node filename and render the next file in the list**. See red arrow where I want the filename to be replaced after each render is complete.  Is this possible?

[image: img1]

Another example
[image: img2]

Added Chris's python code and attached blend file:

[image]

```
import bpy
import glob
import os


print ("Script start")

scn = bpy.context.scene

# here = bpy.path.abspath('//Tex_tures')

here = bpy.path.abspath('/tmp/tex_tures')

output_path = scn.render.filepath

for eachFile in glob.glob(os.path.join(here, '*.png')):
    print(eachFile)
    fileName = bpy.path.basename(eachFile)
    print(fileName)
    fileNameStart = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0]
    print("start:", fileNameStart)
    
    #bpy.data.images['0063.png'].filepath = eachFile # change this to you texture name
     bpy.data.images[fileName].filepath = eachFile # change this to you texture name
    
    directory = os.path.join(here, fileNameStart)
    print("directory", directory)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    scn.render.filepath = os.path.join(directory,"")
    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
    
    
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
```

Upload **tex_tures** file locations:

[image: textures_dir]

Error it gives if Line 23 in the python code is added:

```
Script start
/tmp/tex_tures/2plantpic_test.png
2plantpic_test.png
start: 2plantpic_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rt/Downloads/0-del for questions tmp/blender q/multi_render_tetures.blend/multi_render", line 23, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "2plantpic_test.png" not found'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

[image]

Comment: check out my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218744/86978. Of course you have to adapt it to your needs, but i am pretty sure this is what you want. And it even (as a bonus) takes the name of your texture file ;)

Comment: @Chris yes that's exactly what I'm looking for.  The files are created with your script but it's using the same texture in the image texture node and it's not changing.  I added your python code to the question any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can show us your tmp/tex_tures folder?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this line

```
here = bpy.path.abspath('/tmp/tex_tures')
```

to your folder, else it won't work.

Because the code searches for every png in that folder and then executes it.

Comment: It is changed...I included the python code in the question above along with the blend file.
`here = bpy.path.abspath('/tmp/tex_tures')`

Comment: I downloaded your file and in the python code it wasn‘t changed….

Comment: Very strange I just downloaded the blend file again and that line is in there on `line 12` that's where the textures are located.  `('/tmp/tex_tures')`

Comment: The textures are in the `('/tmp/tex_tures')` directory see image above with directory, are you saying they need to be placed else where?

Comment: Ok, that they are in tmp I couldn’t see 

Comment: What I've found out....I can get the script to create the files and directories with the line `bpy.data.images[fileName].filepath = eachFile` but it looks like Blender isn't sending / setting the new variables / with the `new` file names before any of the renders take place it gives an error if testing with a blank texture in the field so it looks like it's not setting the field to the new texture at all. `GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!` not sure how to fix this though any thoughts?

Comment: all i could do it try out my script on your blender version (if you tell me). My script worked for me as i wrote it (on my version) but i have to say i am working on macbook (maybe this makes a difference although it shouldn't) and i am not that deep in python/files with blender, so i am not sure whether i can help you

Comment: thanks.  I'll post another question to better define the issue and it may also just be a bug.  I'll create a bug report in blender to see if it's a bug with the Linux version.  Thanks again for your help.