# Add a Texture to an Object using Python and Blender 2.8

Tags: python, materials

i have trouble to get a script working within Blender 2.8. The following function work perfectly for me in Blender 2.79, but not in 2.8.

```
def CreateMaterialFromImage(matName, imgPath):
    '''Creates and returns a material from an Image'''
    realpath = os.path.expanduser(imgPath)
    try:
        img = bpy.data.images.load(realpath)
    except:
        raise NameError("Cannot load image %s" % realpath)

    # Create image texture from image
    cTex = bpy.data.textures.new(matName, type='IMAGE')
    cTex.image = img

    # Create material
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(matName)

    # Add texture slot for color texture
    mtex = mat.texture_slots.add()
    mtex.texture = cTex
    mtex.texture_coords = 'UV'
    mtex.use_map_color_diffuse = True
    mtex.use_map_color_emission = True
    mtex.emission_color_factor = 0.5
    mtex.use_map_density = True
    mtex.mapping = 'FLAT'
    return mat
```

It seems to be that the material.texture_slots were removed.

Under following Link https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2018-April/106620.html i found the note:

> - Texture slots for materials, lamps and world were removed. They remain   for brushes, particles and freestyle linestyles.

So my question is where do i find this property now or how could i change my code to get things done?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
https://en.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.8/Source/Python/UpdatingScripts
This seems to be an interesting link for people run in to issues by updating their scripts to 2.8. Unfortunately there is no solution for my problem listed, yet.

Comment: A little correction: It should be `ValueError` instead of `NameError`, name error is for variable not found by name. eg. didn't assign it before access the variable.

Answer (score 15):

I've been able to do this in blender 2.80 as follows:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name=name)
mat.use_nodes = True
bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
texImage = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load("C:\\path\\to\\im.jpg")
mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], texImage.outputs['Color'])

# Assign it to object
if ob.data.materials:
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Comment: I tried this and the texture worked, but it does not show up under properties Texture button. Is there any way to get it added to that?