# How creating function to aplying image to object python

Tags: python, texturing, image

In other answer script not working:
(in [Add a Texture to an Object using Python and Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118646/add-a-texture-to-an-object-using-python-and-blender-2-8) answer not working, generate only black image and delete everything)

```
import bpy nazwa_tek="cyfry" plik_tek_gr="//grafiki/gr.png" tek =
bpy.data.materials.new(name=nazwa_tek) tek.use_nodes = True bsdf =
tek.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"] texImage =
tek.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage') texImage.image =
bpy.data.images.load(plik_tek_gr)
#tek.diffuse_color = (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.8) tek.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'],
texImage.outputs['Color']) print("tekstura:=", tek)

def DodajTeksture(ob, nazwa="cyfry", plik_gr="//grafiki/gr.png"):
    global tek
    # Assign it to object
    if ob.data.materials:
      ob.data.materials[0] = tek
    else:
      ob.data.materials.append(tek)
    return

bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.image_settings.file_format = 'JPEG'
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = './'
bpy.ops.render.render(animation = False) img = bpy.data.images[0]
img.save_render('wynik.jpg')
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath='bb.blend')
```

but how create a image texture? My texture are now procedural and do not have .image value. (I need image texture not procedural)

```
obrazek = bpy.ops.image.open(filepath="//file.png")
bpy.data.images["//file.png"].pack(as_png=True)
```

load image, but how aplying image for object named "Cube"?
[image: how aplying image texture to faces or whole object]

How creating procedure in python

```py
def appimage(obj, name_image, dx, dy)
   #applying image to object name obj staring from (dx,dy) in image
   return
```

create texture, add image to texture (one texture will be assign to some object) specifi region in image for this object. I have big texture for many objects. Only small region is for object. My image have transparent region (it schow diffuse color from bottom?).

```
appimage("Cube", "//file.png", 170, 200)
```

Comment: your answer not working, it generates only black screen and texture, it not assign to texture but remove all informations

Comment: this is not duplicate