# What causes AttributeError: 'Material' object has no attribute 'texture_slots'?

Tags: materials

What causes, in the script below, the error given in the title?

```
if mat.texture_slots[0] == None:
    tex = target_object.material.texture_slots.add()

    tex.texture = bpy.data.texture.new(target_object.name, type='IMAGE')

    tex.texture_coords = 'UV'
# target_object.texture = bpy.ops.texture.new()

    new_image = bpy.data.images.load(image_filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Material.texture_slots` is only available for blender internal render.

[How to add a Texture to a Material using Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48584/how-to-add-a-texture-to-a-material-using-python)

Comment: I'm getting this in the effort to create an old importing plugin for 2.8. Thank you for the pointer. I know nothing about Blender internals. This is the ultimate "just in time learning" project!!