# How to establish material and texture link via python script?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I just learned the below:

```
tl = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.links
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'links'
```

[image]

Comment: bpy.context.scene.node_tree refers to the compositor node_tree. If there's no compositor setup, then there's no node_tree and therefore node_tree.links doesn't exist. If you want the material node_tree you should use bpy.data.materials['yourmaterial'].node_tree.

Comment: @Secrop suspect it's a follow on from  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129948/what-causes-attributeerror-material-object-has-no-attribute-texture-slots

Comment: @batFINGER, yeah, an unfamiliarity with the api.

Comment: sorry, I want to know  how to link the Surface to BSDF or  Color to Base Color in the picture by python script