# How can i enable composite node in python?

Tags: python, node-editor, pynodes

though with the codes i have searched in google , it still doesn't solve the problem, i want to enable one specific composite node like this :

[image]

and this is the inactive state:

[image]

From inactive state to active state , there is only such script indicated in Google

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
compositing_node_tree = scene.node_tree
compositing_node_tree.nodes['os_composite'].select = True
```

But it just functions select node rather than enable node :

[image]

How can i enable this specific composite node in python?
Thanks if you have any ideas!

Comment: What do you mean by "enabling the node"?

Comment: @Pastrokkio  after render , Blender will automatically composite the image using the enabled composite node

Comment: Just to be sure, you've tried with bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True ?

Comment: @Pastrokkio yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set active node**

Similarly to [Set active image node with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14097/set-active-image-node-with-python)

In the python console

```
C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data

>>> node = C.scene.node_tree.nodes['Composite']
>>> node.select = True
>>> C.scene.node_tree.nodes.active = node
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry , it doesn't count , set it to active start is still left "select state" rather than active state ,only difference is this time it is white border rather than red bother (which shows in question part image) around that node.

Comment: The active state should be a red bar in the top of node rather than red or white border around node, you can refer that in my question image.

Comment: Besides , could you please explain what is "C" in your code demo?Thanks