# Bake texture from one mesh to another with existing UV coordinates in Python

Tags: python, texturing, baking

I have a textured **high-poly mesh A**, whose texture I'd like to transfer to its decimated version **low-poly mesh B**, which already has normalized UV textures (generated using [OptCuts](https://github.com/liminchen/OptCuts) so they're nice and compact).

I tried to follow guides such as [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191091/bake-a-texture-map-with-python), getting to the following code, which sadly yields a completely black texture:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'

# remove default stuff
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# load the mesh to bake from and the one to bake to
bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="from_mesh.glb")
bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="to_mesh.glb")

# select the two meshes (glb imports a whole scene)
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
from_obj, to_obj = [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH']
bpy.data.objects[from_obj.name].select_set(True)
bpy.data.objects[to_obj.name].select_set(True)

# create a new image to bake to and assign it to the to_obj material
image_name = to_obj.name + '_BakedTexture'
img = bpy.data.images.new(image_name, 1024, 1024)

for mat in to_obj.data.materials:
    mat.use_nodes = True
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    texture_node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
    texture_node.name = 'Bake_node'
    texture_node.select = True
    nodes.active = texture_node
    texture_node.image = img

# baking
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = to_obj
bpy.ops.object.bake('INVOKE_DEFAULT', type='DIFFUSE', pass_filter={'COLOR'}, save_mode='EXTERNAL', use_selected_to_active=True)

# texture export
img.save_render(filepath='texture.jpg')
```

This is the terminal output:

```
Data are loaded, start creating Blender stuff
glTF import finished in 0.37s
Data are loaded, start creating Blender stuff
glTF import finished in 0.03s
Fra:1 Mem:106.68M (Peak 137.83M) | Time:470417:15:57.15 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene | Synchronizing object | scene_dense_mesh.ply
Fra:1 Mem:122.94M (Peak 137.83M) | Time:470417:15:57.17 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene | Initializing
Fra:1 Mem:122.94M (Peak 137.83M) | Time:470417:15:57.17 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene | Updating Images | Loading finalResult_mesh_normalizedUV.obj_BakedTexture
Fra:1 Mem:122.94M (Peak 137.83M) | Time:470417:15:57.17 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene | Updating Images | Loading Image_0
Fra:1 Mem:122.94M (Peak 137.83M) | Time:470417:15:57.17 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene | Updating Images | Loading Image_0.001
Info: Baking map saved to internal image, save it externally or pack it
```

Intuitively, the code should be doing what I want, but I'm pretty new to Blender's Python API (and Blender in general) so I can't figure out why it's not. Any help / pointers are much appreciated!

Here are links to download [`from_mesh.glb`](http://paste.c-net.org/SwayzakRonna) and [`to_mesh.glb`](http://paste.c-net.org/PrudeNickels).

Edit: changing bake type to 'UV' seems to correctly bake the UV map from mesh A to mesh B, yielding the following: [image: Baked UV map]

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by using `obj` files instead of `glb`.